# iPhone app won't add Strings to Arrays, 64-bit only

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I've just about finished my app and found a bug in my code.  With any of the non-64 bit simulators I can add a String to an array with this code

> [myArray insertObject:currentString atIndex:myArray.count];

This works perfectly with the 32 bit simulators.  However, when I run a 64 bit simulator nothing is added to the array.  The String currentString contains the right data, but when I try and count the size of my array after using the code above, it stays at 0.

Is there some sort of 64 bit way to add to an array that I don't know?

Comment: `addObject:` also insert objects backward. But looks like error in other part of code. Have you checked, is myArray not nil?

Comment: So when I run it on 64 bit, myArray is nil, when I run it on 32 bit it is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your NSMutableArray is alloc ] init 'ed 
OR
make sure you have added

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity://someNumber];
```

before you add objects to your `NSMutableArray`

Also make sure that the objects that you are adding in the array does not have `nil`.
`NSLog` the object before you add it to your array.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This did it.  So, why is it that it worked fine with 32 bit, but not on 64?  The only lines I added were alloc and init and now everything works great.

Comment: No. You always need to alloc-init objects no matter what architecture.

Comment: Can you show is your code surrounding the allocation of the array? Do you create in an if-branch which is false on 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray

addObject:
Inserts a given object at the end of the array.

This is what you are trying to achieve - add your string to end of the array  ?
Or replace the last element of your Array with your string ?

Comment: I'm trying to add an object to my array, and sometimes the array is empty.

Comment: I think what @Mindeater was getting at, is that you can use the much simpler `[myArray addObject:currentString];`, but that won't help you if `myArray` is nil.  You need to figure out why it isn't getting initialised (or is getting released) on the 64 bit processor.  Perhaps show more code